# How to solve $n\times\log_2(n)=10^6$

Tags: logarithms

Sorry for my bad English.

I started to read book about algorithms(Introduction to Algorithms) and there is a problem, I should find a valid  $n$ for $$n \times \log_2(n) = q $$
q might be very big number ($3\times10^{15}$)

I know that I can write a regular brute force program, but it doesn't work, if q is very large number.

Comment: The exact solution uses [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), so... go for numerics, known or home-grown.

Comment: Use a change of basis $\log_2n=\frac{\ln n}{\ln2}$ then solve for $n$ and then as stated by @metamorphy, use the Lambert function.

Comment: In the Wikipedia page, there is a series approximation in terms of the logarithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With $\log_2(n) = \frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(2)}$ your equation becomes
\begin{align}
n \frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(2)} &= q \\
\Leftrightarrow n \ln(n)&= q\ln(2) \\
\Leftrightarrow n \ln(n)&= \widetilde{q}.
\end{align}
Then, perform the change of variables $\widetilde{n} := \ln(n)$. This implies that $e^\widetilde{n} = e^{\ln(n)} = n$. Thus, your equation becomes

\begin{align}
\widetilde{n} e^{\widetilde{n}} = \widetilde{q}.
\end{align}
Using the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), this can be then be (numerically) solved for $\widetilde n = W(\widetilde q)$ and then $n$.